# MAPS. Java. Return of values

Tags: java

I am struggling with following:

I need to create a method which returns a collection of all values that specify some particular selection criterion specified by one or more arguments.
My MAP consists of PPS numbers(keys) and values( town, name, surname, place of work ) Both are strings .
However, I am not sure what I need to do to get the values after placin in the map.

```
/**
*This method returns a collection of all people who work for CO-OP
*/
public Set<String>  selectKeys(String factory)
{
    for (Set<String>eachTaxPayers : taxPayersList.values())
    {
        if(taxPayersList.values().contains(factory))
        {
             Set<String>eachClients = taxPayersList.keySet();
             System.out.println(taxPayersList.keySet());
        }  
    }

    return null ;
}
```

Could someone help me please?

This is a code how Map is populated.

```
public class Tax
{
   Map<String, Set<String>>taxPayersList;

   public Tax()
   {
     taxPayersList = new HashMap<>();
     Set<String>taxPayersDetails = new HashSet<>();
     taxPayersDetails.add(" Eddie Donegan");
     taxPayersDetails.add("Prodieco");
     taxPayersDetails.add("Limerick");
     taxPayersList.put("4481908A", taxPayersDetails);

     taxPayersDetails = new HashSet<>();
     taxPayersDetails.add(" Paddy Power");
     taxPayersDetails.add("Covenant");
     taxPayersDetails.add("Limerick");
     taxPayersList.put("6088989B", taxPayersDetails);

     taxPayersDetails = new HashSet<>();
     taxPayersDetails.add(" Mikey Obama");
     taxPayersDetails.add("Prodieco");
     taxPayersDetails.add("Limerick");
     taxPayersList.put("6788910B", taxPayersDetails);
   }
}
```

I want only to return the key's( PPS numbers) for people who works for the same company

Comment: Show the code of how you define and populate the Map. Also please show the current output and the expected output.

Comment: pczeus, I have edited and added some code, could you have a look at it know ? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at some basic map tutorial? You just need to call `get` on your map and pass in the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Set<String> selectKeys(String factory) {
  // our return Set
  Set<String> factoryWorkers = new HashSet<>();
  // Let's iterate over the map entries
  for (Map.Entry entry : taxPayersList.entrySet()) {
    // Let's grab the value of the current map entruy
    Set<String> eachTaxPayers = entry.getValue()
    // Risky move
    if(eachTaxPayers.contains(factory)) {
      // add the key (PPS) to the return set
      factoryWorkers.add(entry.getKey());
    }  
  }

  return factoryWorkers;
}
```

FYI, the line marked as "Risky Move" is not the best approach.
Though unlikely, it's possible a city has the same name as factory.
You'd be better using an Iterator on the Set and comparing against the 2nd value.
Even better, instead of having a Map>
you could have a Map
where Employee has fields such as name, city and factoryName.